# Xinerama configuration on OpenSuse

Tags: xorg, x11, opensuse, nvidia

Configuration:

- OpenSuse 12.3 installed from the Sage Live CD (http://www.sagecommons.org)
- Latest proprietary NVIDIA drivers
- Dual GTX580s
- Four displays (two per card)
- Displays in a 2x2 arrangement. Bottom two are on card 0, top 2 on card 1
- Gnome

When I enable Xinerama (+ TwinView for each card), I get multiple copies of all of the standard menu items (activities, the log off/etc. menu, etc.) spread across the menu bar. Also, the usable area of the bottom two displays is reduced by about 50%. The menu is at the top of the screens, but the desktop background is squeezed into the middle 50-ish percent.

I can't explain the 50%-ish issue, but it appears that whatever app is creating the menus is running multiple instances. Interestingly enough, there are 5-6 copies of everything, rather than 4 (one per display) that would seem more logical.

Suggestions? If I disable Xinerama, then the problem disappears, but that's not a very usable configuration.

Displays are configured using the `nvidia-settings` application. (On a side note, it appears that all changes are applied to an `xorg.conf` file rather than the files in `xorg.conf.d`.